# how to extract the contents of a strong tag using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
 <li class="bg-blue">
 <img alt="Active Status" src="assets/images/icon-infected.png"/>
 <strong>83004</strong>
 <span>Active Cases</span>
```

I need to extract the values inside the strong tag , how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With beautifulsoup you can use **contents** to get that, just like this.

```
html_doc = """
<li class="bg-blue">
<img alt="Active Status" src="assets/images/icon-infected.png"/>
<strong>83004</strong>
<span>Active Cases</span>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

soup.strong.contents
# 83004
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you find the `strong` element and use `text` for getting the value. You can try it:

```
html_doc = """
<li class="bg-blue">
<img alt="Active Status" src="assets/images/icon-infected.png"/>
<strong>83004</strong>
<span>Active Cases</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

value = soup.find('strong').text
print(value)
```